# Select all Rows in Dynamics CRM Grid

Tags: grid, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

Lets say I have a Grid in CRM showing me Invoices which need to be created by using a custom javascript dialog. In this dialog I want to put two options which are doing the following:

1) selects all Rows flagged as selected in the Grid

2) selects all existing Rows in the Grid

Particularly I have an issue with No. 2)

I cannot figure out how to get all rows if I have lets say 5 pages of invoices. So how can I select all rows in the Grid and not only those shown on the actual grid page?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Regards
Sandro

Comment: I think you have to reconsider this. What would happen if your grid had 1000s of records? the paging is there for a reason

Comment: I'm aware of this. the grid contains max 300 invoices

Comment: Have you tried using the MARK / MARKEDONLY functions on the Dynamics side to set / select records?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late answer. No actually no checked this option. I will check this, thx very much :)

Comment: @DougJ.Huras I think those functions are for `NAV` only

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve only the elements that are *selected* in a grid, then you can use the **Ribbon Workbench** to configure a new button on the sub grid. The Button must have a Command Action which can be configured to pass selected items to a JavaScript method using the `SelectedControlSelectedItemIds` parameter

[image: Parameters]

There is a `SelectedControlAllItemIds` parameter too, but I think this only gives "All Items" in the current page, not all pages. Not sure about these last bits so definitely worth a try

If that doesn't work, then you will have to do this yourself using a `WebApi` call. For example, to get all Contacts associated with an Account, you might do something like this:

```
// Get the ID of the parent account
var accountid = {AccountId};

// Execute a query to retrieve all Contacts associated with the given Account ID
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("contacts", "?$select=contactid&$filter=_parentcustomerid_value eq " + accountid)
.then(
    function(results) { console.log(results); },
    function(error) { console.log(error); }
);
```

Read more about `retrieveMultipleRecords` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrievemultiplerecords)